# Display Gift Messages in Sales Order Grid per Order Magento Admin

Tags: magento, grid

Guys I am very new to Magento So can anyone help me?
Below is my code to get the Gift message on the Sales Order Grid In the Admin :

```
  protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    $collection->join('sales/order_item','`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',array(
    'giftavail' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.gift_message_available SEPARATOR ",")'),
    'giftid' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.gift_message_id SEPARATOR ",")'),
    'skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ",")'),
    'name' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),)

    );
    $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfog' => 'sales_flat_order_grid'),
    'main_table.entity_id = sfog.entity_id',array('sfog.shipping_name','sfog.billing_name'));

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfo'=>'sales_flat_order'),
    'sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sfo.customer_email','sfo.weight',
    'sfo.discount_description','sfo.increment_id','sfo.store_id','sfo.created_at','sfo.status',
    'sfo.base_grand_total','sfo.grand_total'));

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),
    'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id AND sfoa.address_type="shipping"',array('sfoa.street',
    'sfoa.city','sfoa.region','sfoa.postcode','sfoa.telephone' , 'sfoa.country_id'));

    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('gfm' => 'gift_message'),
    'main_table.giftid = gfm.gift_message_id',array('gfm.message'));

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();

}
```

This is the SQL Query that is generated :

"SELECT `main_table`.*, group_concat(`sales/order_item`.gift_message_available SEPARATOR ",") AS `giftavail`, group_concat(`sales/order_item`.gift_message_id SEPARATOR ",") AS `giftid`, group_concat(`sales/order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ",") AS `skus`, group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",") AS `name`, `sfog`.`shipping_name`, `sfog`.`billing_name`, `sfo`.`customer_email`, `sfo`.`weight`, `sfo`.`discount_description`, `sfo`.`increment_id`, `sfo`.`store_id`, `sfo`.`created_at`, `sfo`.`status`, `sfo`.`base_grand_total`, `sfo`.`grand_total`, `sfoa`.`street`, `sfoa`.`city`, `sfoa`.`region`, `sfoa`.`postcode`, `sfoa`.`telephone`, `sfoa`.`country_id`, `gfm`.`message` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS `sales/order_item` ON `sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `sfog` ON main_table.entity_id = sfog.entity_id LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `sfo` ON sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `sfoa` ON main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id AND sfoa.address_type="shipping" LEFT JOIN `gift_message` AS `gfm` ON main_table.entity_id = gfm.giftid GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`"

But this is not working, Can anybody Help???
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Before `$this->setCollection($collection);` line print `$collection->getSelect(); exit;` and run that sql query manually. Then share, if getting any error.

Comment: When I run that query in the Database, i get these error :'#1054 - Unknown column 'main_table.giftid' in 'on clause''

Comment: can you share sql query?

Comment: I am getting the Gift message Id respected to the Order , But I want the Message related to that Gift Message... Has anyone any Idea??

Answer (score 0):

Update you code with below code:

```
protected function _prepareCollection(){

$collection->join(array('order_item'=>'sales/order_item'),'`order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',array(
'giftavail' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`order_item`.gift_message_available SEPARATOR ",")'),
'giftid' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`order_item`.gift_message_id SEPARATOR ",")'),
'skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ",")'),
'name' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'))

);
$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfog' => 'sales_flat_order_grid'),
'main_table.entity_id = sfog.entity_id',array('sfog.shipping_name','sfog.billing_name'));

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfo'=>'sales_flat_order'),
'sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('sfo.customer_email','sfo.weight',
'sfo.discount_description','sfo.increment_id','sfo.store_id','sfo.created_at','sfo.status',
'sfo.base_grand_total','sfo.grand_total'));

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),
'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id AND sfoa.address_type="shipping"',array('sfoa.street',
'sfoa.city','sfoa.region','sfoa.postcode','sfoa.telephone' , 'sfoa.country_id'));

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('gfm' => 'gift_message'),
'order_item.gift_message_id = gfm.gift_message_id',array('gfm.message'));

$this->setCollection($collection);

return parent::_prepareCollection();

}
```

Then you will get working sql query

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, group_concat(`order_item`.gift_message_available SEPARATOR ",") AS `giftavail`,
group_concat(`order_item`.gift_message_id SEPARATOR ",") AS `giftid`, 
group_concat(`order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ",") AS `skus`,
group_concat(`order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",") AS `name`, `sfog`.`shipping_name`,  
`sfog`.`billing_name`, `sfo`.`customer_email`,
`sfo`.`weight`, `sfo`.`discount_description`, `sfo`.`increment_id`, 
`sfo`.`store_id`, `sfo`.`created_at`, `sfo`.`status`, 
`sfo`.`base_grand_total`, `sfo`.`grand_total`, `sfoa`.`street`, 
`sfoa`.`city`, `sfoa`.`region`, `sfoa`.`postcode`,
`sfoa`.`telephone`, `sfoa`.`country_id`, `gfm`.`message` 
FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` 
INNER JOIN 
   `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_item` 
ON `order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN 
   `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `sfog`
ON main_table.entity_id = sfog.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN 
   `sales_flat_order` AS `sfo` 
ON sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN 
   `sales_flat_order_address` AS `sfoa` 
ON main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id AND sfoa.address_type="shipping" 
LEFT JOIN 
   `gift_message` AS `gfm` 
ON order_item.gift_message_id = gfm.gift_message_id 
GROUP BY 
   `main_table`.`entity_id`
```

Issue was with `sales_flat_order_item` table alise name and in last line with gift message. You are using `main_table.giftid` in stead of `order_item.gift_message_id`.

Hope will help!